# Mixing Javascript and HTML vs Maintainable code

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, eval

I have a form with 100+ form controls. My problem is that the form requires non-trivial logic to determine which form controls to hide, show, disable, etc. Right now I have several if-then-else structures in several event handlers that are a nightmare to maintain/update. I have been dabbling in AngularJS and thought I might be able to use something like ng-hide in my JQuery based form. Just to be clear I don't want to switch to AngularJS.

My main questions are: Is this a safe way to use `eval()`? Is there a better way to achieve my goal, while keeping maintainability in mind?

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" ng-show="_isRefill" value="">Test1</button>
 <button type="button" ng-show="_hasChanges || _isRefill" value="">Test2</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
function test()
{

  var _isRefill = true;
  var _hasChanges = false;  

  //There about 10 of these Booleans that control what to show/hide/etc
  //Each DOM element could have it's own unique combination of 10 Booleans that control it  
  //Note that Button #2 has logic in the HTML markup 

  var $this = $(this);

  if( !eval($this.attr('ng-show')) )
    $this.addClass('ignore');
  else 
    $this.removeClass('ignore');

}

$('button').on('click',test);
```

The code inside the `ng-show` attribute is echoed from the server so I don't think I will have an XSS problem, but I could be wrong.

I have considered using something like the observer pattern, but I don't want to create and keep track of a ton of IDs. Also, a lot of my DOM elements are dynamically generated which would make maintaining the subject lists a pain.

**Edit**

Here is an example use case of the form. I took a screenshot of the same section of the form at different states.

**Case 1**
The radio buttons labeled by  "Yes, This is a waiver" and "No, This is not a waiver" determine whether "Waiver Email" and "Business Case" are shown.

**Case 2**
User selects Refill, With Changes, Temporary(TMP) and then is allowed to choose the options from case 1 to show/hide the Waiver section.

**Case 3**
User selects New Position, Intermittent and the Waiver section is forced to Yes and locked.

These are rather simple cases but normally other form controls further down the page can show/hide/disable entire sections or individual form controls. As you can see there are cases where showing/hiding each control has exceptions and overlapping cases.

[image]

Comment: Why would you instead just echo a value... i'm confused as to why you need eval here. you could just parse the string to see what properties it needs, and then access them from a common object. Or just have your server insert classNames and use that to show/hide based on var value.

Comment: @KevinB the booleans,  `_isRefil` for example, are determined based on the value of form controls that the user enters. I can't just parse the string because the expressions in each `ng-show` are different and contain conditional logic. I would basically be writing a compiler.

Comment: a classNames would work fine for that. Simply show/hide a particular className or combination of classNames based on the boolean values. I don't see how doing this with your own implementation of ng-show is any more maintainable.

Comment: @KevinB it's not a 1 to 1 relationship for boolean value to showing/hiding. Example: form control #45 should be shown if boolean1 && boolean2 are true. form control #46 should be shown only if boolean1 is true but only if boolean10 is not true. Make sense? I'm currently doing this and like i said its a giant web of if-then statements and it's hard to maintain.

Comment: No, doesn't really make sense. To me it just seems like the wrong approach was taken from the getgo, so any solution is going to end up being difficult to maintain anyway.

Comment: @KevinB please see my update.

Comment: So, this is a problem that's been around for a long time. No matter what, the logic of when something should show up has to be put somewhere, and maintained. I've seen entire rules engines built for these kinds of things, with rules defined and stored in a database, near-AIs to parse the rules, etc.. It was horrible. We had to maintain the rules, the rules engine, and the interaction between the rules engine and the UI. Honestly, just writing the custom code to do it, in whatever framework or lack thereof, is going to be the easiest, most maintainable way for people to grok your code.

Comment: To answer the question though, no that is not a safe use of `eval()`; anyone can inject malicious code into your `ng-show` attributes and have it evaluated. It will also be slow, since every `eval()` spins up a parser.

Answer (score 1):

Copying part of the AngularJS library is a distinct possibility and you could even generalise by using JQuery to select all of the elements that have a `ng-show` attribute and adding event listeners to add and remove classes.

But you have to consider whether it's worth reinventing part of a very nice, shiny wheel that will definitely give you the result you're after. Maintainability often comes from creating or using a framework, such as Angular JS (I prefer React), that can be reused time and time again before you even attempt to create something specific.

Comment: I have no interest in using any part of AngularJS. I can handle the events/observing in JQuery if i choose to go that route. The main question if i go that route is, Is this an bad way to use eval?

Comment: If a malicious party cannot possibly inject JavaScript into the body of that eval function, then it should be fine.